# Laravel Passport Eror 404 Routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

espero que me podáis ayudar, al intentar acceder a la ruta Api/oauth/Token me aparece el siguiente error, estoy utilizando laravel con jetstreem  para las rutas de web y passport para las rutas de la API.

Si intento acceder a una ruta de la API, generada por mi, si que me carga de forma correcta.

Alguna idea?

Un saludo. y gracias.

```
   {
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "/Users/novamix/Sites/Control/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php",
    "line": 43,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/Users/novamix/Sites/Control/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/CompiledRouteCollection.php",
            "line": 144,
            "function": "handleMatchedRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\AbstractRouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/novamix/Sites/Control/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 647,
            "function": "match",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\CompiledRouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/Users/novamix/Sites/Control/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 636,
            "function": "findRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

vale, ya he encontrado el error, estaba intentado acceder a:

https://miapi.com/api/oauth/token.
y la ruta era https://miapi.com/oauth/token.

para solucionarlo simplemente añadí un prefijo en el AuthServiceProvider

```
Passport::routes(null, ['prefix' => 'api/oauth']);
```

de esa forma puedo acceder a https://miapi.com/api/oauth/token